# Spotify API Token Scope Issue

Tags: spotify

I have been at this for sometime now and wanted to see if anyone had and idea of what I could be doing wrong.  What I am trying to do is add a song to a playlist using the provided Spotify Web APIs.  According to the documentation on this https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/playlists/add-tracks-to-playlist/ I need to establish the scope of the user.

"adding tracks to the current user’s private playlist (including collaborative playlists) requires the playlist-modify-private scope"  I have created the playlist as collaborative and I am using the login credentials of my personal account to reach this playlist I created. all this is under the same login.

What I am finding is that my scope is not getting added to my token on my call for my token causes a 403 error when I try to add the song.
Here is what that call looks like

https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize/?client_id=mynumber&response_type=code&scope=playlist-modify-private&redirect_uri=http:%2F%2Flocalhost:55141/Home/GetToken/

here are the docs on using authorization to get the correct token.
https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize/?client_id=894400c20b884591a05a8f2432cca4f0&response_type=code&scope=playlist-modify-private&redirect_uri=http:%2F%2Flocalhost:55141/Home/GetToken/

further more if I go into the dev support here
https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/playlists/add-tracks-to-playlist/
and click the green try button and then request a new token it works.

Bottom line some how my request is not taking my scope request.  Any Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

To get the token with a specific scope you need to go to the `authorize` endpoint and get the `code`. The `code` is what you want to get to be able http post to the endpoint `https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token` and get a token with your desired scopes. You can simply get the `code` by pasting a url like this in your browser...

```
https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=<client_id>&response_type=code&scope=streaming%20user-read-email%20user-read-private&redirect_uri=<redirect_uri>
```

*Only add %20 in between scopes if you have multiple ones*

You will then be sent to spotify's website and they'll verify you want to do this. Once you verify it your browser will redirect you to what you set the `redirect_uri` to be in the url above. At the end of the url that you are sent to, you should be able to see the parameter name `code` with the code value assigned to it. You then get that code and put it in your http post body params to the `https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token` endpoint. Make sure you accurately follow the query params requirements in your post method.

An example of the post in python using the requests library:

```
authorization = requests.post(
    "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token",
    auth=(client_id, client_secret),
    data={
        "grant_type": "authorization_code",
        "code": <code>,
        "redirect_uri": <redirect_uri>
    },        
)


authorization_JSON = authorization.json()
return authorization_JSON["access_token"]
```

In the end you should get a json that shows the scopes you set a long with a refresh the token later on to make more requests.

I know this answer is quite late but I was experiencing the same issue as well which is how I came across this question. I hope this helps anyone that sees this at a later date.

Source: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#client-credentials-flow